# how can i achieve multiple grep on the same file

Tags: bash, bash-completion

i'd like to be able to do multiple search on the same file and if found on any pattern, perform an action. Currently its only searching for "ERROR" and the idea is to search for "PANIC:" etc. Please advise.
thanks

```
newlog=PG_messages_${day}.new
oldlog=PG_messages_${day}.old
log=postgresql-${day}.log

touch ${newlog} ${oldlog}
mv ${newlog} ${oldlog}

grep "ERROR:" $log > $newlog 2>&1
diff  $newlog $oldlog 1>/dev/null 2>&1

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        diff  $newlog $oldlog >> /tmp/$$
       cat /tmp/$$ 
    fi
}
```

Comment: Look into the `-e`/`--regexp` option: `echo $'foo\nbar' | grep -e foo -e bar`

Comment: as in  ``` grep -e "ERROR:" -e "PANIC:" -e "WARNING" $log ``` ?

Comment: you can provide multiple `-e` and/or `-f` arguments

Comment: Tangentially, [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
grep "(ERROR|PANIC):" $log > $newlog 2>&1
RET_GREP=$?
if [ $RET_GREP -eq 0 ]; then
    # do something when something found
    :
elif [ $RET_GREP -eq 1 ]; then
    # do something when nothing found
    :
else
    # on error...
    :
fi
```

Comment: Hi, Arnaud, the above does not work as it greps nothing resulting in no diff... Here is the output in debug mode ....  `+ grep '(ERROR|PANIC|FATAL):' postgresql-Tue.log
+ diff PG_messages_Tue.new PG_messages_Tue.old
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']' `